# Counting the number of permutations of $(1,\ldots,i,\ldots,j,\ldots,m)$, where $i < j$ and number of inversions is $k$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations

How can I prove the following:

$d^{ij}(m,k) > d^{ji}(m,k)$ for all $k < \frac{1}{2}\binom{m}{2},$

where $d^{ij}(m,k)$ denotes the number of permutations of $(1,\ldots,i,\ldots,j,\ldots,m)$ with $k$ inversions and where $i$ is on the left of $j.$ Similarly $d^{ji}(m,k)$ denotes the number of permutations where $i$ is on the right to $j.$